# Dart Analyzer in a Rail Project is Giving an Error on a Template File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dart, rubymine

I'm trying to set up the dart-rails gem. When I created my first dart code file, I got this error:

```
ERROR: Target of URI does not exist: 'package:rails_ujs/rails_ujs.dart' ([dart_app] dart_app.dart:1)
```

When I double click on the error, it brings up the following file.

```
app/vendor/bundle/gems/dart-rails-0.4.3/lib/dart/rails/generators/templates/dart/dart_app.dart
```

This is the contents of the file:

```
import 'package:rails_ujs/rails_ujs.dart';

RailsUjs ujsHelper;

void main() {
  ujsHelper = new RailsUjs();
}
```

I have this same file in my app/assets/dart directory as well as the package itself. That file is not showing an error. If I change the code to something invalid, an error pops up. This proves the analyzer is looking at it as well.

The error pops up when I run Reanalyze all Dart source files (without restarting Dart Analysis Service). This is a button in the RubyMine IDE. I tried restarting the service and reanalyzing. I get the same error. This issue seems to be that the analyzer is scanning the entire project for dart files. Is it possible to control where the analyzer looks? It's RubyMine that is running the analyzer, not me at a terminal prompt.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Added error message to the question.

Comment: Why do you call the Dart source file a "template file"?

Comment: That's the directory that it is in. I probably could just delete the file since it has done it's job. I still would like to fix the issue as to why the analyzer is looking at it.

Comment: I would need more details. For me it's quite unclear what you're actually doing.

Comment: The analyzer works fine for the normal location. I just ran dart2js from a bash shell on the one program I'm creating and it worked fine. I'm trying to get some information from jetbrains on what the IDE is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a RubyMine issue. I fixed it by placing a file called .analysis_options in the root of the project with the following contents:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - 'vendor/**'
```

I just excluded everything in the vendor directory. Even when I was getting the error, the analyzer continued to process all the valid code files.

Answer (score 0):

If you import the file using

```
import 'package:rails_ujs/rails_ujs.dart';
```

- the file `rails_ujs.dart has to be in the`lib`sub-directory of the directory where the`pubspec.yaml` file is
- he `pubspec.yaml` file needs a `name: rails_ujs` property.
- `pub get` needs to be run from the directory that contains the `pubspec.yaml` file